# css3 doesn't animate in modern browsers when using jquery instead in old browsers

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I have a question that I hope you can help me at this. I'm trying to build a webpage compatible with modern and old browsers. So I use `Modernizr.js` and for `.cssanimations` classes I wrote a code to use css3 when it's supported.

So I wrote the code below:

```
.loaded .main-menu .item:nth-child(2){
top:calc(50% - 25px);
left:calc(50% - 25px);
background-color:yellow;
opacity:0;
}
.cssanimations .loaded .main-menu .item:nth-child(2){
-webkit-animation:moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-moz-animation:moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-o-animation:moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
animation:moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
}
```

instead of these codes:

```
.main-menu .item:nth-child(2){
top:calc(50% - 25px);
left:calc(50% - 25px);
background-color:yellow;
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation: moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-moz-animation: moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
-o-animation: moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
animation: moveicon2 1s forwards 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.05, 1.87);
}
```

And this is my html codes:

```
<html class="no-js cssanimations">
<head>
//
</head>

<body class="loaded">
<section id="sectionOne" class="section section-1">
<div class="main-menu">
<a href="#sectionOne" class="item">A</a>
<a href="#sectionTwo" class="item">B</a>
<div class="item">menu</div>
</div>
</section>
```

But It doesn't work And my animation isn't ran correctly. For some elements it does work but for some else elements the animation doesn't work at all.

Please let me know where was my fault?

Comment: You should add a working code snippet.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I didn't understand what's your point? I did put all codes as possible as it may be necessary.

Comment: I mean https://jsfiddle.net for example.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you are trying to support all browsers, you should avoid using the CSS calc property. Please add a working codepen and the CSS for moveicon2.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found out what's going on. Unfortunately I was using css3 animation and gsap.js animation on same elements. And that's why my animation haven't had good execution. So I changed GSAP to jquery animation on that element and the problem solved. Thanks a lot for comments.